# Cannot Run Hyper V On Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bios, hyper-v, dell-inspiron

I have an Dell Inspiron 3520 laptop with Intel i5 3210M processor which technically supports EPT and VMX. I upgraded to Windows 10.

On Dell BiOS (version A10), I can see just Virtualization Option to enable or disable.

I ran coreinfo with and without Virtualization enabled in BiOS

```
With Virualization Enabled:
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             -       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
With Virualization Disabled:
HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
VMX             *       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             *       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

With Windows 10, Hyper V expects EPT enabled to run emulators. I am not sure how to enable EPT in Dell BiOS. I don't see them responding to the issues in their community.

PS: Windows Phone Emulator was working fine with Windows 8. I have latest BiOS update (2014)

Comment: what version of windows 10 are you using?

Comment: @Keltari It is windows 10 pro edition

Comment: @tchen I am trying to get Windows Phone Emulator up and running so I tagged it to WindowsPhone so that it will get attention from WP devs who work on emulators. I don't see why it should be removed.

Comment: @Lokeshwer I guess if you wanted to narrow down the viewers, you can add the tag. My main concern is: **does Hyper-V work on your system when you try to virtualize other OS**? If not, then the question is more about getting Hyper-V to work as opposed to getting it to work with a specific OS. On the other hand, if Hyper-V *does* work with other OS's, *then* it make sense to add the Windows-phone tag (but in such case, you should also mention that other OS's work in your question).

Comment: What is the actual problem? Do you get errors when enabling Hyper-V feature? When booting a VM?